# how to construct a `np.record` in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

the following code constructs an array with structured dtype

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros(3, dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', bool)]).view(np.recarray)
x = arr[0]
```

`x`'s type is `np.record` and I can use `x.a` and `x.b` to access its types.

How can I construct a similar `np.record` object directly (without creating a `recarray` first) and make its values being `(3, True)`? There is no sufficient information from the [doc of `np.record` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.record.html#numpy.record).

Comment: Your `arr` is a structured array.  `arr.view(np.recarray)` is needed to make a recarray, and to access fields as attributes.  Otherwise you have to use `arr['a']`, not `arr.a`. 
 The `np.recarray` docs are best: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html

Answer (score 0):

To create the object you are looking for, you just need to pass the value and dtype to `np.record` constructor:

```
>>> x = np.record((3, True), dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', bool)])
>>> x.dtype
dtype([('a', '<i4'), ('b', '?')])
```

If you want to work with arrays, instead of initializing your array with `np.zeros()`, you can use [`np.full()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full) instead. This should provide the output you are looking for:

```
>>> np.full(3, x)
array([(3,  True), (3,  True), (3,  True)],
      dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '?')])
```

Comment: Your `x` is a `np.void`, not a `np.record`.

Answer (score 0):

This makes a single element, () shape, structured array:

```
In [380]: arr=np.array((3,True), dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', bool)])    
In [381]: arr
Out[381]: array((3, True), dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '?')])
```

Fields are accessed by name:

```
In [382]: arr['a']
Out[382]: array(3, dtype=int32)
```

The element can be accessed with `[()]` indexing.  `arr.item()` yields a tuple.

```
In [384]: type(arr[()])
Out[384]: numpy.void
```

To make a recarray, use `view`.  Or `np.recarray(...)`, but that's more like using `np.empty`:

```
In [385]: arr=np.array((3,True), dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', bool)]).view(np.recarray)    
In [386]: arr
Out[386]: 
rec.array((3, True),
          dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '?')])
```

Now the element is a `record`:

```
In [387]: arr[()]
Out[387]: (3, True)    
In [388]: type(_)
Out[388]: numpy.record
```

Both the array and the record can use the `.a` attribute (`['a']` still works):

```
In [389]: arr.a
Out[389]: array(3, dtype=int32)    
In [390]: arr[()].a
Out[390]: 3
```

I'm not sure that the `recarray` layer adds much to the structured array functionality.  It feels like a legacy feature.

### edit

```
In [20]: np.record((3, True), dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', bool)]).view(np.recarray)
Out[20]: (3, True)
In [21]: type(_)
Out[21]: numpy.record
In [24]: np.record((3, True), dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', bool)]).view(np.recarray).b
Out[24]: True
```

Comment: In your `In[387]` cell, you need to access the element using `arr[()]` syntax. You didn't directly construct an `record` element.

Comment: So?  `np.record(...).view(np.recarray)` will work.

Comment: The new edit seems to be not working. `In[20]` in your new edit